# Calling class method but got 'str' object has no attribute 'method' error

Tags: python

I have a function to check whether my list of class objects meet a certain criteria, and if they do, they will be stored in a list.

Here is the function:

```
def filter_stories(stories, triggerlist):
"""
Takes in a list of NewsStory instances.

Returns: a list of only the stories for which a trigger in triggerlist fires.
"""
print('checkpoint6, triggerlist', triggerlist)
fired_trigger = []
for trig in triggerlist:
    print('checkpoint7, trig', trig)
    for story in stories:
        print('checkpoint8, story', story)
        if trig.evaluate(story):
            print('checkpoint9, calling evaluate method', trig.evaluate(story))
            fired_trigger.append(story)
return fired_trigger
```

just to illustrate that they are indeed class objects. Here are the results from my terminal:

```
checkpoint6, triggerlist [<__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x0000026C2655A248>, <__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x0000026C26575D88>]
checkpoint7, trig <__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x0000026C2655A248>
checkpoint8, story <__main__.NewsStory object at 0x0000026C26576188>
```

but when I tried to call method of the class object in this line `if trig.evaluate(story):`, I get this error `'str' object has no attribute 'evaluate'`...

Here is my class and subclasses definitions if it is helpful.

```
class NewsStory:
    def __init__(self, guid, title, description, link, pubdate):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.link = link
        self.pubdate = pubdate

    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_description(self):
        return self.description

    def get_link(self):
        return self.link

    def get_pubdate(self):
        return self.pubdate

# ======================
# Triggers
# ======================

class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        # DO NOT CHANGE THIS!
        raise NotImplementedError


# PHRASE TRIGGERS

class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase.strip().lower()

    def is_phrase_in(self, text):
        result = []
        phrase_list = self.phrase.split()
        phrase = " ".join(phrase_list)
        for punct in string.punctuation:
            if punct in text:
                text = text.replace(punct, " ")
        text_list = text.lower().split()
        text = " ".join(text_list)
        result.append(re.search(fr'\b{phrase}\b', text))
        if None in result:
            return False
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        print('TitleTrigger!')


class TitleTrigger(PhraseTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_phrase_in(story.get_title())

class DescriptionTrigger(PhraseTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_phrase_in(story.get_description())


# TIME TRIGGERS

class TimeTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, date):
        try: # if the date supplied is string, strip it into datetime and replace the tz into EST
            date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
            self.time = datetime.replace(date_obj, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))
        except TypeError: # else if it is already in datetime object, replace the tz
            self.time = datetime.replace(date, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))


class BeforeTrigger(TimeTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        story_date = story.get_pubdate()
        try: # if the date supplied is string, strip it into datetime and replace the tz into EST
            story_date_obj = datetime.strptime(story_date, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
            story_time = datetime.replace(story_date_obj, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))
        except TypeError: # else if it is already in datetime object, replace the tz
            story_time = datetime.replace(story_date, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))
        if self.time > story_time:
            return True
        return False


class AfterTrigger(TimeTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        story_date = story.get_pubdate()
        try: # if the date supplied is string, strip it into datetime and replace the tz into EST
            story_date_obj = datetime.strptime(story_date, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
            story_time = datetime.replace(story_date_obj, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))
        except TypeError: # else if it is already in datetime object, replace the tz
            story_time = datetime.replace(story_date, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("EST"))
        if self.time < story_time:
            return True
        return False


# COMPOSITE TRIGGERS

class NotTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, other_trigger):
        self.other = other_trigger

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return not self.other.evaluate(story)


class AndTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger1, trigger2):
        self.trigger1 = trigger1
        self.trigger2 = trigger2

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger1.evaluate(story) and self.trigger2.evaluate(story)


class OrTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger1, trigger2):
        self.trigger1 = trigger1
        self.trigger2 = trigger2

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger1.evaluate(story) or self.trigger2.evaluate(story)
```

Here is the complete error traceback:

```
checkpoint6, triggerlist [<__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x000001DA9D77A088>, <__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x000001DA9D795C88>]
checkpoint7, trig <__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x000001DA9D77A088>
checkpoint8, story <__main__.NewsStory object at 0x000001DA9D799208>
'str' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I don't understand why it is giving me this error as the print statement shows it is an object and not of type string.. and so, very much clueless on how to fix this..
Sorry for the basic question and thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback. My best guess is that one of the "child" triggers of your `AndTrigger` is in fact a string, so `evaluate` fails at that point.

Comment: you get the indentation of the first code block wrong while posting it on this site...

Comment: Besides, **this is not a [example]** -- running the "complete code" doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Although it's great that you tried to do some debugging (printing out values) yourself.

Comment: "and so, very much clueless on how to fix this" Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , but also try to look more closely at the error messages in general, and learn how to trace through the code (recursively stepping into functions and methods as they are called). If you need it, Python [has a built-in debugger, called `pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: This is also a type confusion error; it's the type of problem [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) tackles.

Comment: Thank you @KarlKnechtel for the kind direction. Indeed, the arguments I passed for my `AndTrigger` class is of type string, when it should be of type object. Fixed that and it worked.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a self-answer. // Besides using pdb you can try to reduce the amount of code in the example (see the [mcve] page)

Answer (score 0):

In case this might be of help to anyone who is facing the same error, my problem was when I parsed string as the arguments to my class constructor instead of the intended object type.

This is the class definition:

```
class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase.strip().lower()

    def is_phrase_in(self, text):
        result = []
        phrase_list = self.phrase.split()
        phrase = " ".join(phrase_list)
        for punct in string.punctuation:
            if punct in text:
                text = text.replace(punct, " ")
        text_list = text.lower().split()
        text = " ".join(text_list)
        result.append(re.search(fr'\b{phrase}\b', text))
        if None in result:
            return False
        return True

class DescriptionTrigger(PhraseTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_phrase_in(story.get_description())


class AndTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger1, trigger2):
        self.trigger1 = trigger1 # should be class object
        self.trigger2 = trigger2 # should be class object

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger1.evaluate(story) and self.trigger2.evaluate(story)
```

Here is the function where I instantiate the classes objects:

```
lines = ['t2,DESCRIPTION,Hillary Clinton', 't3,DESCRIPTION,Donald Trump', 't5,AND,t2,t3']

func_dict = {'AND': AndTrigger,
             'DESCRIPTION': DescriptionTrigger} # to map the keyword to class constructor
trigger_dict = {}  # to store all created class objects

for line in lines:
    split = line.split(',')
    if split[1] != 'AND':
       trigger_dict[split[0]] = func_dict[split[1]](split[2])
    if split[1] == 'AND':
       trigger_dict[split[0]] = func_dict[split[1]](trigger_dict[split[2]], trigger_dict[split[3]])
```

So, I have a dictionary called `func_dict` where I store the class constructor as the value to its corresponding key (keyword which I will use to search in `lines`). I then iterate over `lines` and instantiate the class objects depending on the second element of each `line`. If the second element is 'AND', I wanted to create a new object of `AndTrigger` with class object `t2` and `t3` as arguments.

`trigger1` and `trigger2` (see `AndTrigger` class definition) should be class object but I initially instantiated it like so:

```
trigger_dict[split[0]] = func_dict[split[1]](split[2], split[3])
```

here, `split[2]` is `'t2'` and `split[3]` is `'t3'` from here `'t5,AND,t2,t3'`. They are of type string.

Instead, I should have parsed the instantiated class object stored in `trigger_dict` as the argument.

```
trigger_dict[split[0]] = func_dict[split[1]](trigger_dict[split[2]], trigger_dict[split[3]])
```

Hope that helped!